# if subsequence of even terms and odd terms both converge to L, prove the whole sequence converge to L

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

if ${S_n}$ is a sequence of real numbers and if 
$$\lim_{2m \to \infty} S_{2m} = L$$ 
$$\lim_{2m-1 \to \infty} S_{2m-1} = L$$ 
then prove
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n} = L$$

This is how I began:
let $\epsilon>0$
There exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $|S_{2m}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $m\ge N_1$ and 
There exists $N_2\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $|S_{2m-1}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $m\ge N_2$  
Now let $n=\text{max} \{N_1 , N_2\} $ ( my curly brackets do not show. sorry about that )
Now I guess I have to prove that 
$|S_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n \ge m$
But I am not sure how to do that. or even have I been correct in the beginning?
I will appreciate your help with this question .

Comment: You can write \{ for $\{$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take $m$ as the maximum of $2N_1$ and $2N_2-1$. Suppose $n \geq m$. Consider the cases $n$ even and $n$ odd. In the first case use the fact that $\frac n 2 \geq N_1$ and in the second case use the fact that $\frac {n+1} 2 \geq N_2$. You should be able to see that $|S_n-L| <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

We should consider

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} S_{2m} = L \quad \lim_{m\to \infty} S_{2m-1} = L$$

and you are done by taking $M=\max \{2N_1 , 2N_2-1\}$ indeed for all $n\ge M$

$$|S_n-L|<\epsilon$$